# Why knitr or Markdown is deleting files?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I created a markdown document to put it in www.pubs.com. When I run this code the file is created but the three files are deleted of the directory so I can´t run the markdown again. How do I avoid it?

I do not understand why the creation of the Rmd document deletes the files to open.

````
```{r, cache= FALSE, warning=FALSE}
setwd("D:/personal/data science/Capstone Project/final/en_US")
news<-readLines("en_US.news.txt", 1000)
blogs<-readLines("en_US.blogs.txt", 1000)
tweets<-readLines("en_US.twitter.txt", 1000)
```
````

Comment: I'm not sure (this isn't [reproducible](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000)), but I would skip the `setwd()` and try `ddir <- "D:/personal/data science/Capstone Project/final/en_US"; news <- readLines(file.path(ddir,"en_US.news.txt"), 1000); ...`

Comment: thank you. I learnt something new. However I tried your suggestion but, It does not work. I have the same trouble

Comment: this is https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/580 ...

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue few days ago, just lock the files and tried to rerun the codes, its works for me.

Comment: can you explain more?  what do you mean by "just lock the files"?

Comment: Right click and changed the properties of selected files to be read only.